# How to insert current date time into a Sitecore email template

Tags: sitecore

I have a form with an `Send Email` action. I'm about to use the field placeholders, but I'm not sure if its possible to use ASP like syntax to print out  the current date time etc.

Is this possible with Sitecore? Or do I need to add an additional field and make it invisible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand your questions correctly:

You have an email template which will have fields in it. You need to store current date time in that field?

You can do that my injecting a pipeline when item is getting created and store the current date time to that field. There are various sources where you can find out how to intercept between pipelines in Sitecore.

Hope it helps :)